# Aspnet-codegenerator could not find .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to scaffold .NET Identity files as have been shown here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization

The problem is when I run 'aspnet-codegenerator' command, it show me this error:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.0-rc.2.20475.5' was not found.
- The following frameworks were found:
  3.1.10 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I've already installed .NET 5:

```
dotnet-sdk.dotnet --version
5.0.100
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you can create a file named "global.json" in the directory where the solution is located and do its contents as follows;

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "5.0.100",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```